# How can I find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I have 2-3 different column names that I want to look up in the entire database and list out all tables which have those columns. Is there any easy script?

Comment: Refer this: http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/mysql-search/

Answer (score 1680, accepted):

To get all tables with columns `columnA` or `ColumnB` in the database `YourDatabase`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

Comment: @Echo - you can always play with mysqldump with --skip-extended-insert and then grep through the file... dirty but strangely satifying :)

Comment: @Echo, for versions prior to 5 dump the structure to file using mysqldump, see my answer.

Comment: @kaii I would like to add more question on how will search including its type as PK. e.g. statement that goes: where COLUMN_NAME ='<column name>' and <should be a primary key>

Comment: @raf Try DESCRIBE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;      
COLUMN_KEY = "PRI" should do the trick

Comment: You can also use `DATABASE()` instead of a string to search in the currently selected database.

Comment: @Ken : is there a way to add one more filter to your query ? Indeed, selecting the tables where de columnA has a specific value.

Comment: @FredFLECHE I think at that stage I would just loop through them in a script and keep it simple

Comment: @Ken. Actually while waiting for your input I used a php script to do the simple and effcient solution you just suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, especially useful when your coworker adds column manually instead of doing it in the migration script

Comment: If you are looking for tables that must have ALL columns, this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752116/mysql-select-all-tables-with-multiple-specific-columns

Comment: What it would be the approach for ColumnA AND ColumnB (not or) ?. So which tables contains those two columns, not at least one of those.

Comment: @Sherlock, I can't get your tip work with MySQL 5.6.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 8.0.25. I met a problem that this query also returns VIEW names. And I want to filter out them. I used a subquery `... WHERE ... AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase'))` Any ideas to improve this?

Comment: @Ken Can you help me in my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69005703/join-two-tables-and-extract-the-lowest-price-with-multiple-conditions-multiple

Comment: Kindly let me know if this is also correct?
SELECT t.table_name,c.column_name
   FROM information_schema.tables t join information_schema.columns c on t.table_name=c.table_name
Where 
   t.TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('bayut_main') and c.column_name like 'userid%'

Comment: @Hegwin Another way to filter out views is to join on `information_schema.tables` and filter on `table_type = 'BASE TABLE'`

Answer (score 265):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%wild%';
```

Comment: If there are multiple databases, add a WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="" line also.

Comment: Thanks John, how will the query if I need to get Table names which has columnA and ColumnB present?

Comment: @JohnMillikin: or conversely, if you don't know the database but only the field name, leave it out and add `TABLE_SCHEMA` to the fields of the return set to see all databases + tables that contain that column name.

Comment: Shouldn't that read either: like '%wild%' or = 'wild' instead of like 'wild'?

Comment: I just tried this but noticed all the results I got where for objects that don't show up with the query `show tables;`. Can anyone explain why this might be the case?

Comment: @wdkrnls you missed the first comment below this solution. Your results are from other dbs, while show tables shows you only the currently selected db's columns.

Comment: I would just add TABLE_SCHEMA and I'd be happy with it.
I'm voting this because it is the closest match to how I modified Ken's answer.

Answer (score 62):

More simply done in one line of SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'column_name';
```

Comment: Are there any disadvantages of using * here?

Comment: @GuneyOzsan the only disadvantage is getting more data than just the table name, which is what the OP was asking for

Answer (score 42):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE column_name LIKE 'employee%'  
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase'
```

Answer (score 21):

In older MySQL versions or some MySQL NDB Cluster versions that do not have `information_schema`, you can dump the table structure and search the column manually.

```
mysqldump -h$host -u$user -p$pass --compact --no-data --all-databases > some_file.sql
```

Now search the column name in `some_file.sql` using your preferred text editor, or use some nifty [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) scripts.

---

And a simple [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) script to find the column. Just replace *COLUMN_NAME* with yours:

```
sed -n '/^USE/{h};/^CREATE/{H;x;s/\nCREATE.*\n/\n/;x};/COLUMN_NAME/{x;p};' <some_file.sql
USE `DATABASE_NAME`;
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME` (
  `COLUMN_NAME` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
```

You can pipe the dump directly in sed, but that's trivial.

Comment: Versions of what? MySQL? What is an "ndb"? [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB)? Or something else? As much as possible, please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11952827/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). For example, by linking to what a "ndb" is.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I appreciate your intentions, but as it's a 10y old answer can't remember exact versions or so, I rephrease it and use MySQL NDB Cluster instead of simply ndb, hope it's cleared now.

Answer (score 17):

For those searching for the inverse of this, i.e. looking for tables that do not contain a certain column name, here is the query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name' AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT 
TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 
'column_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name');
```

This came in really handy when we began to slowly implement use of InnoDB's special `ai_col` column and needed to figure out which of our 200 tables had yet to be upgraded.

Answer (score 14):

Use this one line query. Replace *desired_column_name* by your column name.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'desired_column_name';
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to "get all tables only", then use this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%'
and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tresbu_lk'
```

If you want "to get all tables with columns", then use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE '%'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='tresbu_lk'
```

Answer (score 10):

```
select distinct table_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name in ('ColumnA') 
    and table_schema='YourDatabase';
    and table_name in 
    (
        select distinct table_name 
        from information_schema.columns 
        where column_name in ('ColumnB')
              and table_schema='YourDatabase';
    );
```

That ^^ will get the tables with ColumnA *and* ColumnB instead of ColumnA *or* ColumnB  like the accepted answer

Comment: Does that actually work? What about the first semicolon? In any case, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the gist of it? What version of MySQL did you test it on? Etc. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59382822/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%city_id%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with information_schema is that it can be terribly slow. It is faster to use the SHOW commands.

After you select the database you first send the query SHOW TABLES. And then you do SHOW COLUMNS for each of the tables.

In PHP that would look something like

```
    $res = mysqli_query("SHOW TABLES");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {   $rs2 = mysqli_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$row[0]);
        while($rw2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs2))
        {   if($rw2[0] == $target)
               ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you quantify *"terribly slow"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54826287/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).