# How can I get column names from a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to query the name of all columns of a table. I found how to do this in:

- [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/452464/419956)
- [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193780/419956)
- [PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/22362/5089)

But I also need to know: **how can this be done in *Microsoft SQL Server* (2008 in my case)?**

Comment: As a quick&dirty trick, I really like to do `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 1=0`

Comment: @bgusach - Seems like the user wanted the names of columns as rows in a table, but for what you're trying to do, `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM my_table` is less keystrokes

Comment: `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'`; only change the table_name

Answer (score 1270, accepted):

You can obtain this information and much, much more by querying the [Information Schema views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

This sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'
```

Can be made over all these DB objects:

- [CHECK_CONSTRAINTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/check-constraints-transact-sql)
- [COLUMN_DOMAIN_USAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/column-domain-usage-transact-sql)
- [COLUMN_PRIVILEGES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/column-privileges-transact-sql)
- [COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql)
- [CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/constraint-column-usage-transact-sql)
- [CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/constraint-table-usage-transact-sql)
- [DOMAIN_CONSTRAINTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/domain-constraints-transact-sql)
- [DOMAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/domains-transact-sql)
- [KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/key-column-usage-transact-sql)
- [PARAMETERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/parameters-transact-sql)
- [REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/referential-constraints-transact-sql)
- [ROUTINES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routines-transact-sql)
- [ROUTINE_COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routine-columns-transact-sql)
- [SCHEMATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/schemata-transact-sql)
- [TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/table-constraints-transact-sql)
- [TABLE_PRIVILEGES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/table-privileges-transact-sql)
- [TABLES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql)
- [VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/view-column-usage-transact-sql)
- [VIEW_TABLE_USAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/view-table-usage-transact-sql)
- [VIEWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/views-transact-sql)

Comment: what does "N" in "= N'Customers'" stands for ?

Comment: Qbik "N" if for handlling unicode string like varchar in ANSI(32bit) and nvarchar in unicode(64bit)

Comment: confirmed: works for **MariaDB** too ! :) (without `Nortwind.` ... )

Comment: ```SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tableName';``` this works for me

Comment: I had to use `TABLE_SCHEMA = '?' AND TABLE_NAME = '?'` since I'm on localhost and I have multiple tables with the same name but in different databases.

Comment: If you don't get the exact table name use TABLE_NAME like 'Customers' instead of TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'

Comment: This throws errors for me in Microsoft SQL Server, but `SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('table_name')` worked.

Comment: This doesn't give you columns for materialized views.

Comment: How can we do it with a temporal table?
If I try SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'#Mytemporaltable' it doesn't give any output.

Answer (score 218):

You can use the stored procedure sp_columns which would return information pertaining to all columns for a given table. More info can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx

You can also do it by a SQL query. Some thing like this should help:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTableName')
```

Or a variation would be:

```
SELECT   o.Name, c.Name
FROM     sys.columns c 
         JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE    o.type = 'U' 
ORDER BY o.Name, c.Name
```

This gets all columns from all tables, ordered by table name and then on column name.

Answer (score 182):

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='tableName'
```

This is better than getting from `sys.columns` because it shows `DATA_TYPE` directly.

Comment: +1 since this is standard ANSI SQL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) Other answers like sys.objects are not standard

Comment: And if the table is in another schema (the SQL server "schema" variant) add `AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaName'` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Very useful, and you can add `JOIN sys.types t on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id` and add `t.name` in your 'SELECT' statement to get the **types** next to each column name as well.

Answer (score 64):

You can use `sp_help` in SQL Server 2008.

```
sp_help <table_name>;
```

Keyboard shortcut for the above command: select table name (i.e highlight it) and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: this is my all time favorite keyboard short-cut.  I also assign sp_helptext to Cntl-F1.  Together these two shortcuts save so much time!

Comment: sp_help does not work for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2020.
But writing [tablename], highlighting it and pressing ALT+F1 does. Thanks

Answer (score 52):

By using this query you get the answer:

```
select Column_name 
from Information_schema.columns 
where Table_name like 'table name'
```

Answer (score 50):

You can write this query to get column name and all details without using 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA in MySql :

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM database_Name.table_name;
```

Comment: @Benjamin, because this question is for SQL Server and this answer is for MySql

Comment: May be most of the peoples using MySql, faces this problem. And I have mentioned it. I am using MySql.

Comment: It doesn't matter if most people using other RDBMSes have the same problem, it's irrelevant to the original question and pushes relevant answers further down.

Comment: I downvote because the question is specifically address to mssql

Answer (score 31):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TABLE_NAME')
```

`TABLE_NAME` is your table

Answer (score 30):

```
--This is another variation used to document a large database for conversion (Edited to --remove static columns)

SELECT o.Name                   as Table_Name
     , c.Name                   as Field_Name
     , t.Name                   as Data_Type
     , t.length                 as Length_Size
     , t.prec                   as Precision_
FROM syscolumns c 
     INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id = c.id
     LEFT JOIN  systypes t on t.xtype = c.xtype  
WHERE o.type = 'U' 
ORDER BY o.Name, c.Name

--In the left join, c.type is replaced by c.xtype to get varchar types
```

Answer (score 20):

You can try this.This gives all the column names with their respective data types.

```
desc <TABLE NAME> ;
```

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, table_name,ordinal_position, is_nullable 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name LIKE 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

Answer (score 18):

You can try using :-

```
USE db_name;
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

it'll give you column names with the type.

Answer (score 17):

Summarizing the Answers

I can see many different answers and ways to do this but there is the rub in this and that is the `objective`.

Yes, the objective. If you  want to `only know` the column names you can use

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 1=0
or
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM my_table
```

But if you want to `use` those columns somewhere or simply say `manipulate` them then the quick queries above are not going to be of any use. You need to use

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'
```

one more way to know some specific columns where we are in need of some similar columns

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like N'%[ColumnName]%' and TABLE_NAME = N'[TableName]'
```

Answer (score 17):

In SQL Server, you can select COLUMN_NAME from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 16):

Just run this command

```
EXEC sp_columns 'Your Table Name'
```

Comment: its not giving the desired result

Answer (score 14):

This SO question is missing the following approach :

```
-- List down all columns of table 'Logging'
select * from sys.all_columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('Logging')
```

Answer (score 11):

It will check whether the given the `table` is **[Base Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503(v=sql.100).aspx)**.

```
SELECT 
    T.TABLE_NAME AS 'TABLE NAME',
    C.COLUMN_NAME AS 'COLUMN NAME'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON T.TABLE_NAME=C.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE   T.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
            AND T.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Your Table Name'
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like N'%[ColumnName]%' and TABLE_NAME = N'[TableName]'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT c.Name 
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE o.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TABLE_NAME')
ORDER BY c.Name
```

Answer (score 6):

One other option which is arguably more intuitive is:

```
SELECT [name] 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[yourSchemaType].[yourTableName]')
```

This gives you all your column names in a single column.
If you care about other metadata, you can change edit the SELECT STATEMENT TO `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and doesn't require sys variables:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM suppliers;
```

Comment: mysql version 5.7.33.  It it does not work

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like N'%[ColumnName]%' and TABLE_NAME = N'[TableName]'
```

**OR**
If you want to view the column names, you can select the table and press `Alt+F1`.

Comment: This answer is not adding anything not provided in earlier answers, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38116877) that was posted 7 years before yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP (0) [toID]
      ,[sourceID]
      ,[name]
      ,[address]
  FROM [ReportDatabase].[Ticket].[To]
```

Simple and doesnt require any sys tables

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 0 from table
```

it give you table with one row ( the names of the feilds)

but most of the time i prefer to run  `select top 5` in order to see data examples (it easy to see and run 5 rows )

Answer (score 0):

Some SQL Generating SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
  col001 INTEGER
, col002 INTEGER
, col003 INTEGER
, col004 INTEGER
, col005 INTEGER
, col006 INTEGER
, col007 INTEGER
, col008 INTEGER
, col009 INTEGER
, col010 INTEGER
)
;
INSERT INTO test(col001) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO test(col002) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO test(col005) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO test(col009) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

SELECT
  CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ordinal_position)
  WHEN 1 THEN 
    'SELECT'+CHAR(10)+'  *'+CHAR(10)+'FROM test'
   +CHAR(10)+'WHERE '
  ELSE
    '   OR '
  END
+ column_name +' IS NOT NULL'
+ CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ordinal_position DESC)
  WHEN 1 THEN 
    CHAR(10)+';'
  ELSE
    ''
  END
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema='dbo'
    AND table_name = 'test'
ORDER BY
  ordinal_position;

-- the whole scenario. Works for 10 , will work for 100, too:

-- out -----------------------------------------------
-- out  SELECT
-- out   *
-- out FROM test
-- out WHERE col001 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col002 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col003 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col004 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col005 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col006 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col007 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col008 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col009 IS NOT NULL
-- out     OR col010 IS NOT NULL
-- out ;
```