# SQl select specific column but with use of *

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need help, my SQL Server select statement is:

```
select * from schematemplate.scanner
```

the columns of this table are:

```
id
Asset_Category
Asset_Classification
Brand
Model
Supplier
Color
```

I can select all the columns except the `Asset_Category` and `Asset_Classification` by using this:

```
Select id, brand, model, supplier, color 
from schematemplate.scanner
```

But I don't want to specify the columns that I will select like the code above.

Is it possible to use `SELECT * from schematemplate.scanner` and add a code like `EXCEPT asset_category and asaset_classification`?

Comment: There are many topics on this. The answer is no. You can create a view as suggested below.

Comment: @PinnyM- because my tables are changing the column names and no. of columns, i want a select statement that will select all except asset_category and asset_classification.

Comment: @njk - ok now i know that i cannot do that kind of statement, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it dynamically, e.g.:

```
declare @s varchar(max) = 'select '

select @s=@s+name+',' from sys.columns
where object_id=object_id('schematemplate.scanner')
  and name not in ('asset_category','asset_classification')
order by column_id

set @s=substring(@s,1,len(@s)-1)+' from schematemplate.scanner'

exec(@s)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27309/5/0)

Comment: @RoronoaZoro it may have been from the schema name. I've edited the answer to use "schematemplate.scanner" can you give it a try?

Comment: still have error but i replace the other one with "schematemplate.scanner". And its finally working!!!
Thank you very much sir this is what I am looking for! I will accept it as an answer and +1! thanks again :D

Answer (score 3):

Those are only five columns. Why not select it?

Anyway, here's a suggestion that you may take,

- create a view and
- run select on it,

example

```
CREATE VIEW viewScanner
AS
SELECT id, brand, model, supplier, color 
FROM   schematemplate.scanner
```

and when you want to select records,

```
SELECT * FROM viewScanner
```

Comment: thanks but this answer is not helping and i am not lazy, the reason is that may table is changing the number of columns, its not always the id, brand, model, supplier, color. It can be id, brand, Part_no, Size.

That is why i cant a statement that will select all columns except the asset_category and asset_classification

Comment: *changing the number of columns* -- physically? or you only mean during the projection of the result?

Comment: hmm to be more clearly, In my code, there is a button that will select the column depending on what the user choose from the dropdownlist.

here is the code: select * from schematemplate."& dropdownlist.text &"

that's why i cannot use what you suggest

Comment: @RoronoaZoro Are you able to `SELECT` the column names to populate the drop down list and just omit the columns you don't want? Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/get-columns-of-a-table-sql-server).

Comment: in your front-end, why not create a string that concatenates the selected columns on the dropdownlist.text?

Comment: @njk -  i am not populating the dropdown by the use of select