# How to test for existence of a specific set of fields in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, field

I want to be able to test if a table has a specific set of fields (I'll settle for name comparison only; of course, types/lengths/etc could have been changed).  I see that testing for existence of individual fields is not that difficult, but the table I am dealing with has about 80 fields, and I am hoping to not have to go through each one.

The main goal here is to perform a sanity check in code, to confirm the table hasn't been changed, so when records are copied, no fields are missed.

Comment: Any reason you can't just query the meta tables/views?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your query should be

```
SELECT count(*)
 FROM DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName' and COLUMN_NAME='YourColumnName'
```

If count>0 then it Exist

Comment: I think this should do it, with some minor mods. I'll change ``COLUMN_NAME='YourColumnName'`` to ``COLUMN_NAME IN (...)`` to get all the columns, test that the final result is indeed equal to that number, and also test for the absolute number of columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
if
(SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG='your_db' 
AND 
TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE' 
AND 
COLUMN_NAME='COLUMN_NAME')>0
..
```