# select column names of current table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, button

I have a database created in SQL Server 2014 and I've linke it with a project written in C# in Visual Studio. I created a ComboBox in which I get the names of all the tables from my database and a get button which shows the content of the current table when I click on it.

My question is, how can I acces the current columns one by one? Because I want to create Insert, Delete, Update buttons, and I need the name of the columns from the current table for that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server

Comment: I've read that, but I want to work with the column from a current table one by one... I don't know how to select them

Comment: Are you asking how to query and fetch the column names for a given table?

Comment: If I insert data into the gridview, how can i save it?

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

  reader.Read();

  var table = reader.GetSchemaTable();
  foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
  }
}
```

Comment: It says: "The name command does not exist in the current context"

Comment: create an objet of sqlcommand command= new Sqlcommand(param1,param2) and use it . or you can take reference from here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx