# Select numbered column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic select query which supposed to fetches columns as `col1`, `col2`......`col9`, `col10` but it fetches incorrectly as `col1`, `col10`, `col11`, `col12`, `col2`.... Not sure how to select them as the query is dynamic.

Please help.

This is the dynamic select I have been using.

```
-- CREATE THE COLUMNS REQUIRED 
SET @DYColumns = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT 
    ',' + N'sourceID' 
    + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (PARTITION BY prgmg_product_id ORDER BY prgmg_product_id, source_id_other) 
         AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
    FROM #Prgmg FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '');
```

Comment: show your query! how you are writing the query?

Comment: The code snippet is easier to debug than your paragraphed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Drop Table #Prgmg
CREATE TABLE #Prgmg (
    prgmg_product_id INT
    ,source_id_other INT
    );

INSERT #Prgmg (
    prgmg_product_id
    ,source_id_other
    )
VALUES (3310,11478)
    ,(3337,10833)
    ,(3354,11466)
    ,(4039,4846)
    ,(4039,65454)
    ,(4039,65456)
    ,(13337,110833)   -- Added to force over 10
    ,(13354,111466)   -- Added to force over 10
    ,(14039,14846)    -- Added to force over 10
    ,(14039,165454);  -- Added to force over 10


DECLARE @DYColumns NVARCHAR(1000)
    ,@DYSqlQuery NVARCHAR(4000);

--  CREATE THE COLUMNS REQUIRED
SET @DYColumns = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' 
                    + N'sourceID' 
                    + right('00'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY prgmg_product_id, source_id_other) AS NVARCHAR(10)),2)
            FROM #Prgmg
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '');



-- CREATE THE DYNAMIC SQL AND ADD IN THE CREATED COLUMNS
SET @DYSqlQuery = '
    SELECT prgmg_product_id,' 
        +   @DYColumns 
        +   ' FROM (
                SELECT prgmg_product_id
                    ,CAST(N''sourceID'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY prgmg_product_id ORDER BY prgmg_product_id, source_id_other
                        ) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Col
                    ,source_id_other
                FROM #Prgmg S1
        ) X
        PIVOT(MIN(source_id_other) FOR Col IN (' + @DYColumns + ')) P'

Print @DYSqlQuery
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @DYSqlQuery;
```

Returns  -- Notice the Columns are in Order.  This was done by zero padding the Row_Number()

```
SELECT prgmg_product_id,sourceID01,sourceID02,sourceID03,sourceID04,sourceID05,sourceID06,sourceID07,sourceID08,sourceID09,sourceID10 FROM (
            SELECT prgmg_product_id
                ,CAST(N'sourceID' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY prgmg_product_id ORDER BY prgmg_product_id, source_id_other
                    ) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Col
                ,source_id_other
            FROM #Prgmg S1
    ) X
    PIVOT(MIN(source_id_other) FOR Col IN (sourceID01,sourceID02,sourceID03,sourceID04,sourceID05,sourceID06,sourceID07,sourceID08,sourceID09,sourceID10)) P
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using COALESCE or STUFF to build your columns, make sure there is an ORDER by

Furthermore, you could have col01,col02,..col10 to ensure the sequence

Comment: How to select dynamically as col01,col02,col03..then

Comment: There are many techniques on building Dynamic SQL.   I would have to see your technique to better advice.

Comment: --  CREATE THE COLUMNS REQUIRED
SET @DYColumns = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' 
                    + N'sourceID' 
                    + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prgmg_product_id ORDER BY prgmg_product_id, source_id_other) AS NVARCHAR(10))    
            FROM #Prgmg
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '');
This is one am using...

Comment: --CREATE THE COLUMNS REQUIRED 
SET @DYColumns = STUFF((
 SELECT DISTINCT ',' + N'sourceID' + right('00'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prgmg_product_id ORDER BY prgmg_product_id, source_id_other) AS NVARCHAR(10)),2) 
    FROM #Prgmg
 FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '');

Comment: Added padded zero on the column name -- assuming not more than 99 columns

Comment: Or you can add ORDER BY prgmg_product_id, source_id_other after the FROM #Prgmg

Comment: I am a little concerned over the PARTITION BY prgm_product_id.   If you have multiple, the Row_Number will reset and potentially cause two Col01's

Comment: Yes john you can also see my question in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595058/sql-server-dynamic-columns-creation  where you could see  the input also ...is there an alternate way i could try???

Comment: OK, I got the sql from the linked question.  Give me a moment

Comment: See the new answer posted