# Column Name not displayed in listbox in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Now, when the previous issue got resolved, there is a new issue that has risen.
When I run my code, it gives me the column name as(which is obviously not my column name):

```
System.Data.DataRowView
```

The code that I am using is:

```
            private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (textBox1.Text == "select" || textBox1.Text == "SELECT" || textBox1.Text == "SELECT")
                {
                    string cmdstr = @"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '" +comboBox1.SelectedItem+ "'"; 
                    string conStr = @"Data Source=INPDDBA027\NGEP;Initial Catalog=Dev_Server;Integrated Security=True";
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conStr);
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    listBox2.DataSource = dt;

            }

        }
```

Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get column names from a table in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*INFORMATION_SCHEMA* is your way:

```
SELECT 
COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableNameHere'
```

You need to execute this using `SqlCommand`, and use the result as a `dataSource` for your `ListBox`. Like this:

```
private static List<string> ReadTableColumns(string connectionString)
{
    List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
    string queryString = 
        "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " +
      + "WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableNameHere'";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                columnNames.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    return ColumnNames;
}


listBox1.Datasource = ReadTableColumns(yourConnectionString);
```