# Getting the list of SQL select columns from JOOQ parser

Tags: jooq

I need to get the list of columns in a select using the JOOQ SQL parser. In the example below it would return the list with two entries: 'sk' and 'aa'. Debugging the program I can see in the `Query.select` field the list of columns, but I cannot find in the `Query` class a method to retrieve them. How to get the list of columns?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Query`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Query.html) object model returned by the [jOOQ parser API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-api) does as of jOOQ 3.12 not provide any corresponding accessors. This feature is however planned for the next minor release (3.13).

The following answer gives you an example how you might be able to use the existing [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) SPI to achieve your goal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006668/1732086.

Comment: Thanks. `VisitListener` didn't work for me, so I tried to use reflection with the apache commons library: `java.lang.reflect.Field f = FieldUtils.getField(Query.class, "select", true);` I can see in the result the column names, but I cannot cast it How to get the list from `f` ? SelectFieldList class is not public or I cannot use it.

Comment: I also tried Java reflection with `Field f = Query.class.getDeclaredField("select");` but cannot get the values from f as I'm not sure what class to cast.

Comment: I solved it: I did a toString() of the result and split it.