# How Can I see an empty table structure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm using terminal for mysql

I want to know what column my table has, but it's empty and dont show anything to me

- `Show Databases;`

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

- `Use test`

`Database changed`

- `Show Tables;`

```
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| tblPerson      |
| tblStudent     |
+----------------+
```

What Should I do to see the column of my table, even if its empty, like this:

```
+----+-----------------+---------+
| id | name            | is_male |
+----+-----------------+---------+
|    |                 |         |
+----+-----------------+---------+
```

not this:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Show create table <table name>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get column names from a table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type this command you will get the column names of your table.

```
desc tblPerson;
```

Answer (score 2):

Show table structure: **describe [table];** or **desc [table];**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `describe`, of course.  You can also use `information_schema.columns`.  Or, you can just `select`:

```
select p.*
from tblPerson p
limit 0;
```