# Query column range in database table?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to query column ranges for a SQL Server table?

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{table}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get column names from a table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: what do you mean by `column ranges` ?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by column ranges and provide some sample output of what you expect to return from the query.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic SQL to apply a column name filter:

```
DECLARE @DynamicQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @DynamicQuery = 'SELECT '+STUFF((SELECT  ',' +name AS [text()] FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=object_id('TABLE')

    -- Add column range filter here.
         AND name LIKE 'N%'  
    -- Or, if column names are numeric, cast and compare range
         -- AND cast(name as int) BETWEEN 10 AND 20 

    ORDER BY  name FOR XML PATH('')),  1, 1, '')+' FROM TABLE';
    EXEC(@DynamicQuery)
```