# List column name for user views in oracle

Tags: oracle

What is the Query for list the column names for user created views in Oracle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
      table_name,
      column_name,
      data_type
 FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'VIEWNAME'
  AND owner      = 'OWNER'
ORDER BY column_id
```

You can also use `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and/or `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` depending on your privileges and whether you have permission to query the view.

Comment: Below query worked fine 


SELECT
      TABLE_NAME,
      COLUMN_NAME
   FROM
      ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE
      TABLE_NAME LIKE 'View Name'

Comment: This also works for materialized views, is it worth to mention it in the answer?

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'your_view_name'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```