# How to create a list of column names?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, drop-down-menu

I have a question about creating a list of column names from table. I have table with different activities like Football, Basketball, Volleyball,... I want to take all of these sports and put them in the list that way I can limit my query later based on the sport which user selected in drop down. Can anyone help mi with this problem?

```
Select *
From Activities
Where (sleceted sport) = 'Basketball';
```

Comment: I think usually you take integers as value and simply replace it with the names in the ui

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a SQL query to do this for you you can look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739203/oracle-query-to-fetch-column-names) Or [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844979/list-column-name-for-user-views-in-oracle)

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Activities';
```