# How to populate the excelsheetcloumn names into a dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

Hi i have an excel sheet with headers,i want to populate those headers into a dropdown list...

can any one help me with the select statement and procedure

i am working on a code i dnt know whether its correct or not

```
      DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
                    string connectionstring = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", Excelpath);  
                    string query1 =  String.Format("select * from [{0}]", DDlist.SelectedItem.Text);                                             
                    // OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query1, connectionstring);                                                
                    using (OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand odc1 = new OleDbCommand(string.Format(query1, conn1));
                        conn1.Open();
                        OleDbDataReader dr;
                        dr = odc1.ExecuteReader();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            list.Items.Add(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString());
                        }
                        dr.Close();
                        conn1.Close();
                    }
```

in this method i am geting an error at this line

```
    dr = odc1.ExecuteReader();Error:ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.
```

can any one help mw with this, thanks in advance

Comment: try 'OleDbCommand odc1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn1);'

Comment: throwing errot at "list.Items.Add(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString());""System.IndexOutOfRangeException: CUSTOMER_ID"...@Nalaka526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it may work.....

```
                  foreach (DataTable table in DS.Tables)
          {
               foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                   DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
                   string connectionstring = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", Excelpath);
                   string query1 = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", DDlist.SelectedItem.Text);                                                                      
                   using (OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
                   {
                       OleDbCommand odc1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn1);
                       conn1.Open();
                        DataTable dte = null;
                       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                       dte = conn1.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                       OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                       objAdapter1.SelectCommand = odc1;
                       objAdapter1.Fill(ds, "xldata");
                        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
                       {
                           list.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString());
                       }
                       conn1.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: i think this one suits my answer better from all the answers..thank you@Anil

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing Connection to OleDBCommand. So try,

```
OleDbCommand odc1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class has two main parameters to be passed for a proper execution. That are Query and connection object. In your code you are passing the connection, but it is placed inside the `String.Format()`, so place it outside. See the code below....

```
OleDbCommand odc1 = new OleDbCommand(string.Format(query1, conn1));
```

TO

```
OleDbCommand odc1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn1);
```

Comment: throwing errot at "list.Items.Add(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString());""System.IndexOutOfRangeExcept‌​ion: CUSTOMER_ID"...

Comment: Your select statement is little big wrong, select only column names from the table. Go to this link to select only columns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table

Comment: That statement is for geting the column names from database....how can i use in excel

Comment: When you get the only column names from a query result, you can use directly like "list.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString())" ok.