# Get column name for a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a query that returns me name of columns of a table.

I tried following query -

```
SELECT column_name ColName 
  FROM all_tab_columns 
 WHERE table_name ='<TABLENAME>';
```

but this query is returning duplicate column names.

I do not want to use `distinct` in my query cause it hampers the performance.

So is there a query which returns columns of a table without any duplicate.

Comment: Do you have the same table in multiple schemas in this DB?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have more than one table named '<tablename>' owned by different schemas? Try adding `OWNER = '<schemaowner>'` to your where clause.

Comment: Right please filter this with owner too ,and you'll get the desired output

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get column names from a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table)

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution for getting column name from table.

```
    select column_name,data_type from cols where Table_name='TEST_TABLE'
```