# Query columns names from a table from another user

Tags: oracle, data-dictionary

Sounds pretty easy query the column names from a table, right? Indeed there is a answer to this question [How can I get column names from a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table)

The main issue is that the table belongs to another user. My user is just for integration and I don't have any database privileges.

So I'm able to do some query like: `SELECT * FROM anotherUser.THE_TABLE;`

But something like `SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS` return no rows.

Perhaps I can create queries over all_tab_columns, Are there another faster options without procedures?

*It´s a oracle database!

Comment: :`user_tab_columns` is a data dictionary that will contains columns of the table ,which belongs to your schema ,not `anotherUser`,if you want try with `all_tab_columns` or dba_tab_columns`.Please have a look to this `http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1001.htm#i1572007`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE OWNER='ANOTHERUSER' 
   AND TABLE_NAME='THE_TABLE';
```

Should get you there if you have privileges on the table.