# Joining column names to column values

Tags: oracle

I have a table that looks like this

```
col1 | col2
-----------
  1  |  a
  2  |  b
  3  |  c
```

and I want to run a query that makes it look like this

```
val | colname
-------------
  1 | col1
  2 | col1
  3 | col1
  a | col2
  b | col2
  c | col2
```

I've read about [unpivot](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506) and I've figured out [how to get the column names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452476/322909). Here's the query I am currently working with.

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    myTable 
UNPIVOT (
            val 
        FOR 
            column_name 
        IN (
               SELECT 
                   column_name 
               FROM 
                   USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
               WHERE 
                   table_name = 'myTable'
           )
        )
```

Comment: Should we assume that your desired results are to have 2 and 3 in the `val` column rather than repeating a `val` of 1 in 3 different rows?

Comment: @JustinCave, yes. I will fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, why can't you use this. The `UNPIVOT` requires that all data be of the same type, so you mush cast data as needed:

```
select value, colName
from
(
  select to_char(col1) col1,
    col2
  from yourtable
) 
unpivot
(
  value
  for colName in (col1, col2)
) 
order by value
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05b3b/4)

Result:

```
| VALUE | COLNAME |
-------------------
|     1 |    COL1 |
|     2 |    COL1 |
|     3 |    COL1 |
|     a |    COL2 |
|     b |    COL2 |
|     c |    COL2 |
```

Comment: `The UNPIVOT requires that all data be of the same type` this was my main problem. Thanks.

Comment: follow up question what are `src` and `un`?

Comment: @johnthexiii they are aliases for the stuff inside the parentheses.  They are not needed for Oracle.  I am used to SQL Server syntax where it is required.  I undated my solution.