# Returning only the column names from a SELECT statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select

This is just a lazy thought. I have a table with about 9 columns names. Is there any way I can use SQL statement to return only the Column names? The normal way is to write out my column names from

```
SELECT * FROM tableName;
```

statement but was wondering if I can get the column names with SQL statement.

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks You!

Comment: I suppose that this is a request for Sql Server right?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If it is SQL Server I would be inclined to use the system views (e.g. sys.columns) rather than the information schema for reasons outlined [in this article by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Comment: Hi Bro, this statements would be used via the code behind file in an ASP.NET application. I need to get the result set then parse the returned values to a dropDownList control which will then be used for further quesries. 

So in a nutshell...would be using SQL Server when the application is finally deployed to the life Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get column names from a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table)

Comment: @RameshRajendran that question is about Oracle

Comment: @stuartd Not oracle only.about sql there

Comment: @stuartd, See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20856606/2218635

Comment: @RameshRajendran the question is tagged Oracle, and the accepted answer is querying the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` table. The fact that most of the answers are for SQL Server doesn't change that. And why have you posted a link to your answer in this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get columns of a table SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/get-columns-of-a-table-sql-server)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
```

Should do it

Answer (score 1):

```
SET FMTONLY ON
SELECT * FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Open you Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, in New Query, Just type your Table name and select it and then press <kbd>ALT + F1</kbd> Key, it will give all details about table

Answer (score 0):

Try following SQL statement to get column name.

```
SELECT column_name   
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='tableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can query the **syscolumns** table for table column metadata.

```
 SELECT [name] AS [Column Name]
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE  [Name] = 'TableName')
```

See this image that query return values

[image]

Referred from : [How can I get column names from a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table)

and [another one way](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5995c1d8-44d7-4b2b-85f7-6bfc0daa3e58/how-to-get-all-field-names-in-a-table-using-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this method alongside with the others in the answers to my question but I got only the COLUMN NAME header as my result. So decided to use a datatable to get the result of the normal sql SELECT * FROM tableName statement, binded it to a gridView, used the HeaderRow.Count property of the GridView to get the HeaderNames, passed same into a DataTable, then Populated my Drop Down List Control with the results.

Answer (score 0):

select column_name,* from information_schema.columns
 where table_name = 'YourTableName'
order by ordinal_position

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server xml raw you get the column names from any sql query. Replace 'select top 1 * from [TABLENAME]' from the example below. Query must return at least 1 row of data and remember to use top 1.

```
declare @t1 table (x xml)
declare @t2 table (x xml)
declare @t3 table (x xml)

insert into @t1 select cast( (select top 1 * from [TABLENAME] for xml raw) as xml)
insert into @t2 select y.r.query('.') from @t1 cross apply x.nodes('/row') as y(r)
insert into @t3 select t2.n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') from @t2 t cross apply x.nodes('//@*') as t2(n)

select replace (convert (nvarchar, x),'_x0020_', ' ') from @t3
```