# Oracle how to find all column that match a particular column name

Tags: oracle, match, multiple-columns

I want to identify all columns within a database whose name matches with a given input column and whose datatype matches with the given input column. Can someone suggest a query for this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get column names from a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the accepted answer on that linked question is helpful here, too.

Comment: Might be not. How will we ensure that we are getting the columns of same datatype ?

Comment: @user2783058 You can use my link to get started with. You should at least have tried something yourself - it is not that complicated if you read the answers from the linked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... all columns within a database whose **name** matches with a given input column and whose **datatype** matches with the given input column

You can use the `all_tab_columns` data dictionary view. For example, to select all columns of type `NUMBER` and where the column name starts with `"A"`, use something like

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE data_type='NUMBER' AND column_name like 'A%';
```

```
TABLE_NAME             COLUMN_NAME            DATA_TYPE
---------------------- ------- ------------------------------
AUDIT_ACTIONS          ACTION                 NUMBER
SDO_CS_SRS             AUTH_SRID              NUMBER
APEX_WS_APP_PAGES      APPLICATION_ID         NUMBER
...
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry, this may be a basic question, but I have a urgent requirement : how do we get all the columns within the table as well as other tables that match a particular column ? The result shouldn't contain the column we are comparing with. For example, as in above example, I want all columns within as well as other tables similar to A but we should not display A in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

for example if i want to look for column with the name 'CELL' in table 'INT_TRN_RLDEP_CELL', then the query would be

`select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name like 'INT_TRN_GRN_RLDEP_CELL' and COLUMN_NAME like 'CELL';`

for more information visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_metadata or oracle documentation on tables metada