# Find duplicate rows without distinct and table columns SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to remove the duplicate records from my table and want to have just one copy of that duplicate row.

I searched for the solutions, but all the solutions involves table columns, which I can not use.

Actually, I have tables having more than 800 columns, so obviously I can not use column names into query.

I know we can use DISTINCT but is there any solution for this wihtout using DISTINCT?

Please help me out!

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, you have to do that for 800 columns?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Which answer are you referring to?  You can open the question again if the OP provides actual data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The answer marked as correct have a group by for each column

Comment: What other option is there?  Using row number with a partition also requires listing every column which determines a duplicate.  The problem here is that a single table having 800 columns is bad design in my opinion.

Comment: @dang what is the problem with using `DISTINCT`? Why you have a table with 800 fields? Why cant use column names?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I have to perform this operation dynamically through PL/SQL for any table. I don't have exact columns available at any given point in time. So, I plan to pass any table to this function, and it would remove duplicate rows.

Comment: Well with the table name you can get all the [**column names**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-oracle) and create a dynamic query. But you have to build a query like Tim suggest.

Comment: Would distinct work faster than group by? I want to eliminate any duplicate rows.

Comment: Probably similar performance.