# How can I get column names from CTE(common table expression) in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a function that gives the names a common table expression(~ a subtable in a with statement).

I would like a function f like that

```
with a as (select 1 a from dual) select f(a.*) from a
```

> column1=a

Or perhaps are the CTE saved somewhere?

I could do something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-oracle).

Is there a equivalent of USER_TAB_COLUMNS for the CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`DBMS_SQL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html) package to parse the statement and get the column names:

> ```
> declare
>   cur integer;
>   cols dbms_sql.desc_tab;
>   num_cols integer;
> begin
>   cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor();
>   /*Prase statement*/
>   dbms_sql.parse(
>     c => cur,
>     statement => q'{
>       select dual.*, 'something' as qwe
>       from dual
>     }',
>     language_flag => dbms_sql.native
>   );
>   /*Get cols*/
>   dbms_sql.describe_columns(
>     c => cur,
>     col_cnt => num_cols,
>     desc_t => cols
>   );
>   
>   for i in 1..num_cols loop
>     dbms_output.put('Col index: ' || i);
>     dbms_output.put_line(' Col name: ' || cols(i).col_name);
>   end loop;
>   dbms_sql.close_cursor(cur);
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> dbms_output:
> Col index: 1 Col name: DUMMY
> Col index: 2 Col name: QWE
> ```

Or with a local function declaration, if you want it to be `select`able:

> ```
> with function get_cols(
>   p_stmt in clob
> ) return sys.odcivarchar2list
> as
>   pragma autonomous_transaction;
>   ret sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
>   cur integer;
>   cols dbms_sql.desc_tab;
>   num_cols integer;
> begin
>   cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor();
>   /*Prase statement*/
>   dbms_sql.parse(
>     c => cur,
>     statement => p_stmt,
>     language_flag => dbms_sql.native
>   );
>   /*Get cols*/
>   dbms_sql.describe_columns(
>     c => cur,
>     col_cnt => num_cols,
>     desc_t => cols
>   );
>   
>   for i in 1..num_cols loop
>     ret.extend();
>     ret(i) := cols(i).col_name;
>   end loop;
>   dbms_sql.close_cursor(cur);
>   
>   return ret;
> end;
>
> select column_value as col_names
> from get_cols(p_stmt => q'{select dual.*, 'something' as qwe from dual}')
> ```
>
> ```
> | COL_NAMES |
> | :-------- |
> | DUMMY     |
> | QWE       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=75ca5e5ee5580b60863df5ffeffc1d0d)*

Answer (score 0):

No. A CTE is *part* of a DML (data modification language) statement.
You wrote it, you should know what columns are in it!

If you need to know the column list of a completed SELECT statement, SELECT ... INTO a temporary table - the column list will then be visible in USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

Answer (score 0):

with a CTE it is not possible. You can write your own function to parse your sql statement. Maybe in your function you can create table with **1=2** condition to get just column names then drop it in your function.

Otherwise;

you can create your table :

```
create table your_table
as
with a as (select 1 a from dual) select a.* from a where 1=2
```

then find like this:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
```

Comment: View should be sufficient, it looks more lightweight to me.