# My table has two timestamp values and remaining are string value. I want to display entire table in html using php

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to display entire sql table without knowing column names of that table. This table contains emp_id,emp_name,joining date,resignation_date,emp_address,emp_phone.

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection established";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $selected_table = $_POST['cycle'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$selected_table;
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
        if (!$result) {
            $message = 'ERROR:'.mysql_error();

            return $message;
        } else {
            $i = 0;
            echo "<html><body><table><tr>";
            echo "the row value is ".sqlsrv_num_fields($result);
            while ($i < sqlsrv_num_fields($result)) {
                $meta = sqlsrv_get_field($result, $i);
                echo "<td>".$meta['name']."</td>";
                $i = $i + 1;
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            $i = 0;
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "rows are ".count($row);
                $count = count($row);
                $y = 0;
                while ($y < $count) {

                    $c_row = current($row);

                    echo "<td>".$c_row."</td>";
                    next($row);
                    $y = $y + 1;
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                $i = $i + 1;
            }
            echo "</table></body></html>";
            sqlsrv_free_result($result);
        }

    }
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
```

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: Why are you referencing SQL Server functions (i.e. `sqlsrv_connect`) and MySQL functions (i.e. `mysql_error`)? Also, something like `$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$selected_table;` is a **huge** injection issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the MySQL table structure in PHP? Plus a list of all tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468458/how-do-i-get-the-mysql-table-structure-in-php-plus-a-list-of-all-tables)

Answer (score 0):

**Notes about your error:**

One explanation here is, that by default PHP Driver for SQL Server returns `smalldatetime`, `datetime`, `date`, `time`, `datetime2`, and `datetimeoffset` types as PHP DateTime objects. So, in this case, you have two options:

- to parse the date as string using PHP `DateTime::format`
- to set the `'ReturnDatesAsStrings'` option in the connection string to `true`. By default this option is `false`.

In your case, if you *... want to display entire sql table without knowing column names of that table ...*, you should use the second option:

```
<?php
    // Connection
    $server = "server\instance";
    $cinfo = array(
        "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true,
        "Database" => "database",
        "UID" => "username",
        "PWD" => "password"
    );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
    if( $conn === false )
    {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }

    ....
?>
```

**PHP example:**

You have issues with your script:

- the statement with *... Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string ...*  error is probably `echo "<td>".$c_row."</td>";`
- `mysql_error()` is function from different PHP extension. Use `sqlsrv_errors()` instead
- you do not need to call `current()` and `next()`  PHP functions to get each item in an array. Use `foreach($array as $key => $value) { ... }` instead.
- you need to call `sqlsrv_field_metadata()` function to get field information.

You may try with the next example, that will generate your expected output:

```
<?php
# Connection
$server    = 'server\instance';
$database  = 'database';
$uid       = 'username';
$pwd       = 'password';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true,
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# SQL statement
$tablename = '[YourTable]';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_prepare): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Columns names
echo '<table id="'.$tablename.'">';
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
$metadata = sqlsrv_field_metadata($stmt);
if ($metadata === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_field_metadata): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
foreach($metadata as $field) {
    echo "<td>".$field['Name']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";

# Table rows
echo "<tbody>";
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_execute): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
    };
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";

# End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```