# query to display the names of databases that contain specific table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have multiple databases in mysql server but want to search the location of a specific table .Can u help me in locating the databases that contain specific table.I am working in command mode. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Look up in `COLUMNS` table in `information_schema` database.

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME` 
    from `COLUMNS` 
    WHERE 
        `COLUMN_NAME` = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME';
```

You need **root** privilege for this. or at least *`SELECT`* permission on `Information_schema` table.

Answer (score 0):

Below link might help you...

[How to find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

Please let me know incase of further queries...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This link gave me the hint and I solved it as follows-> select table_schema from 

information_schema.tables where 

table_name='tablename';

Comment: Ahh I remember now... `select * from tables` gives all tables that are present in database... BUT was not sure of PATH....