# How can I alter multiple tables at once in mysql?

Tags: mysql, alter

I am trying to alter multiple tables and change the size of the `username`  VARCHAR column to 999 as its current size is too small and now things are screwed up. How can I do this?

I have tried the following and it worked for one table but when trying to update multiple table names it returned errors:

```
ALTER TABLE  `TABLE_NAME` CHANGE `username` VARCHAR( 999 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can we see the detail of the error ?

Comment: Can't you do this one by one or write a script to do it?

Comment: @julesanchez it is a syntax error, but because I'm working with so many tables the error is too long. And @jakx I would like to `ALTER` for each table but can't seem to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can try with 2 tables, and display the error ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it with a single query. You need to query `information_schema` views to get the list of tables and columns to change. You will then use the resulting resultset to create `ALTER` queries (either in an external application/script or within MySQL using cursors and prepared statements)

Comment: How can I query `information_schema`? Could you show me an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them/193860#193860

Answer (score 3):

I found the only way to do this was via an external file.  This is my implimentation :

```
function changeSchema($oldName, $newName, $type, $len)
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME = '$oldName' AND 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'");
    if($res)
        while($line=mysql_fetch_object($res))
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `$line->TABLE_NAME` CHANGE `$oldName` `$newName` $type( $len ) NOT NULL ");
    }
}
```

I then was able to modify any table I wanted easily.

Comment: is this php or a function that used in query ?

Comment: @Gagantous That is definitely PHP and Raath posted in 2012 which is likely why he wasn't using MySQLi yet. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Write a query file to alter all tables and execute that file.