# Mysql change deault value of float default value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change default value of float data type in mysql I have many tables with float value but wherever my data is more than 5 values it is rounding the values.

For Example I have this value:

```
2254798
```

And it is converting it to:

```
2254800
```

I have many table with these problems is there any way I can retain exact value. When I am changing  float length to 25 it is working fine. Is there any way I can set the default float value to 25 length for all my table in my database.

Comment: You won't be able to do it in a single query using just mysql. As you will need to query the information_schema table to get all the tables and columns and than run `ALTER TABLE` script based on that result. One way would be using a stored procedure and/or a cursor if you want to do it in just mysql. Or use [PHP example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10490243/2911633)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are not exact in MySQL.  If you require exact storage, consider using `DECIMAL` with some default value:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    some_col DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 123.45
    ...
)
```

Comment: For all table is there any way I can change float to decimal for all table. I have more than 200  tables.

Comment: Look into using `ALTER TABLE` to change the column type.  I don't know of a way to do this for 200 tables, not without writing a script.