# How can I find all columns where the column name length is greater than 5?

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

I have a database named bbs, which have 37 tables. ***I want to find all columns in these tables where the column name length is greater than 5!***

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_rails_bb  |
+---------------------+
| articles            |
| articles_categories |
| bookmarks           |
| categories          |
| comments            |
| drafts              |
| extension_groups    |
| extensions          |
| forum_tracks        |
| forums              |
| icon_items          |
| icons               |
| levels              |
| management_groups   |
| management_logs     |
| message_folders     |
| message_tos         |
| messages            |
| moderators          |
| posts               |
| replies             |
| reports             |
| roles               |
| roles_users         |
| schema_migrations   |
| sessions            |
| smiles              |
| subscribes          |
| system_configs      |
| topic_tracks        |
| topics              |
| upload_files        |
| users               |
| users_forums        |
| users_topics        |
| warnings            |
| word_replacements   |
+---------------------+
37 rows in set (0.25 sec)
```

How to write the sql?

Comment: try my solution below. Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, its a rails bbs app! i want to add prefix to some column but i should check which way is the best? change db or change my code. thank you for your reply^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you will change here is the name of your database (`Table_Name`, `Column_Name` are fixed). try this one:

```
SELECT Table_Name, Column_Name 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'databaseName' -- <= Database Name Here
HAVING CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) > 5
ORDER BY Table_Name, Column_Name
```

or you can also select all fields

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'databaseName' -- <= Database Name Here
HAVING CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) > 5
ORDER BY Table_Name, Column_Name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) > 5
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

Not tested! Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them) and edited the query. Something like this should at least get you started :)

Answer (score 1):

Just query the information_schema database:

```
mysql> connect information_schema;
mysql> select table_name, column_name from columns where table_schema = 'bbs' and char_length(column_name) > 5;
```

Take into account that char_length(str) will give you the amount of characters str have while length(str) will result in the size in bytes of str.