# Search database if column name/field name exists in a table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to search the database if a column name / field name exists in a table in mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use INFORMATION_SCHEMA database and its tables.

eg :

```
    SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = 'MY_DATABASE'
       AND column_name IN ( 'MY_COLUMN_NAME' );
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename LIKE 'columnname'
```

have fun ! :-)

*UPDATE:*

As mentioned in the comments, this searches only one table, not the whole database (every table). In that case, please refer to DhruvPathak's answer.

Comment: That would just search 1 table instead of whole database.

Comment: hmm ok - well i did understand the question if a certain column is in a certain table!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to search in the whole database then you should try

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

And if you want to search in the particular table then you should try

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want search two or more columns use following below metioned.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```