# How do I search a MySQL database for a specific column name?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to find if my database has a column named `sort_method`. I have had a look around the forums, but I don't seem to be able to find the right answer. My database has over 300 tables, so manually looking for it is not an option.

I'm using SQL queries from [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin).

Comment: Dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name,table_schema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name='sort_method'
```

Answer (score 8):

You can query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` system table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'sort_method'
```

More information is in *http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html*.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"Page Not Found"*

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'columnName'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```