# SQL Query to lookup a column

Tags: sql, view, lookup

I want to lookup if a column by the name of 'LOB' exist among thousands of views.
Schema name: PACONE

any help is appreciated here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That solution will depend on what Database Server you have.

If you have Oracle, go to [Search an Oracle database for tables with specific column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953239/search-an-oracle-database-for-tables-with-specific-column-names)

If you have mySQL, go to [How do i search a mysql database for a specific column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009961/how-do-i-search-a-mysql-database-for-a-specific-column-name)

If you have PostgreSQL, go to [How to find a table having a specific column in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508422/how-to-find-a-table-having-a-specific-column-in-postgresql)

If you have SQL Server, this is a possible solution:

**How-To: Find Fields or Tables Within a SQL Server Database**

Suppose you need to find a field called GLASS_ID, you simply run this:

-- SEARCHING FOR A CERTAIN FIELD NAME --
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'GLASS_ID'

Similarly, you can look for all field names that end with 'CO'

-- SEARCHING FOR FIELD NAMES THAT END WITH... --
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE '%CO'

Of course, this is supposed to work under SQL Server, and that was tested in SQL Server 2005 only, but I guess that it will work in any recent version too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 use [your database name]
 SELECT t.name AS table_name,
 SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
 c.name AS column_name
 FROM sys.tables AS t
 INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
 WHERE c.name = 'LOB'
 ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Comment: Can you help me plug in the variables, bc I am getting errors here;
Schema name: PACONE
looking for table has a 'LOB' column

Comment: Which database server are you using ? My solution works with Microsoft sql server. You should add that to your tags

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should provide some information about your environment.

If you use Oracle you can query the dba_tab_columns with dab_view (user_ or all_ is also possible) e.g.:

```
select a.view_name 
from dba_views a 
join dba_tab_columns b 
on a.view_name = b.table_name 
where lower(b.column_name) = 'lob'
and lower(b.owner) = <view_owner>;
```