# Search and get tablename which has a given column name?

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

Can I write an sql query that can find the names of all tables in a database that have column name like %COL_FAX_ID%. If so, how?

Database used is oracle or db2.

Answer (score 6):

For Oracle, you could try:

```
SELECT owner,
       table_name,
       column_name
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE column_name LIKE '%COL_FAX_ID%'
 ORDER BY owner,
          table_name;
```

For a full list of the Oracle data dictionary views etc. see [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/tahiti/tahiti.catalog_views).

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an oracle install lying around to test this with but you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%COL_FAX_ID%'
```

Comment: I'd use ALL_TAB_COLS rather than ALL_TAB_COLUMNS as per the Oracle definition: This view (ALL_TAB_COLS) differs from "ALL_TAB_COLUMNS" in that hidden columns are not filtered out

Answer (score 0):

Dublicate of possible [How to find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

Answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

Edit:
Sorry I Miss saw the sql for beeing mysql tag...
But this may work aswell? Dunno. Gl & Hf

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name like %'COL_FAX_ID%'
```

Comment: I'd use `ALL_TAB_COLS` rather than `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` as per the Oracle definition: This view (ALL_TAB_COLS) differs from "ALL_TAB_COLUMNS" in that hidden columns are not filtered out.

Comment: Regarding the author would like to get table name all_tab_columns is fine as well but many thanks at any case

Answer (score 0):

For oracle:

```
SELECT table_name,column_name from all_tab_columns 
where column_name like '%COL_FAX_ID%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For DB2, you will want to use the [`SYSCAT.COLUMNS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html) catalog view.

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE COLNAME LIKE '%COL_FAX_ID%'
```