# How to select specific table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

I want to select tables from sql where the table has a column named "TimeStamp". How do I list all the tables where those tables that will be selected has a column named "TimeStamp" in it? I am using MySQL.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do this? Could you not use a static `array()` that contains the proper tables in it?

Comment: You can use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: I did cite my sources, @TiessonT. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'timestamp'
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

Done and done.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)