# How to get table structure at a time for many?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database say **test**. It contains 10 tables. I know I can do `describe <table_name>` to get skeleton of that table. But I have to do that for each table individually.

This is my problem. Any query or script I can write to get the skeleton of all those tables at time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them try this

Comment: @spaceman thanks but its not i want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns Where TABLE_SCHEMA='test';
```

Comment: Thanks vignesh. can you help me with how to save output to a excel sheet ?

Comment: @rajagenupula: You should better post a new query for answer on db to excel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-queryu-output-to-excel-or-txt-file

Comment: @rajagenupula I have posted answer there in the name of Vignesh Kumar .please check it

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) can be told to skip data and dump only table schema.

```sh
mysqldump --no-data test
```

Use options `-u <user>` to connect as `<user>` and `-p` to ask for password. Maybe you also want `--compact` to be less verbose and possibly other. Many adjustments to the contents can be made using other options.