# How to save MySQL query output to excel or .txt file?

Tags: mysql, excel

How do you save output of a MySQL query to a MS Excel sheet?

Even if it's only possible to store the data in a `.txt` file, it will be okay.

Comment: if you are using phpmyadmin, there is an option to export as csv or excel ect

Comment: @KrishR where may I know ? I am pretty new to workbench

Comment: Which OS version you have ? Linux or windows?

Comment: - Goto PHPmyadmin in browser and choose database
    - Execute your sql query in the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin or select tables.
    - After execution / after select the table , scroll down the page and look for "Query results operations"
    - Click "Export" link and there is a page to export all the results you can select desired format

Comment: You can [Format Table Data as Text table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34084279/1045444).

Answer (score 292, accepted):

From [Save MySQL query results into a text or CSV file](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/):

> MySQL provides an easy mechanism for writing the results of a select
> statement into a text file on the server. Using extended options of
> the INTO OUTFILE nomenclature, it is possible to create a comma
> separated value (CSV) which can be imported into a spreadsheet
> application such as OpenOffice or Excel or any other application which
> accepts data in CSV format.
>
> Given a query such as
>
> ```
> SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
> ```
>
> which returns three columns of data, the results can be placed into
> the file /tmp/orders.txt using the query:
>
> ```
> SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
> INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.txt'
> ```
>
> This will create a tab-separated file, each row on its own line. To
> alter this behavior, it is possible to add modifiers to the query:
>
> ```
> SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
> INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
> ENCLOSED BY '"'
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
> ```
>
> In this example, each field will be enclosed in double quotes, the
> fields will be separated by commas, and each row will be output on a
> new line separated by a newline (\n). Sample output of this command
> would look like:
>
> ```
> "1","Tech-Recipes sock puppet","14.95" "2","Tech-Recipes chef's hat","18.95"
> ```
>
> Keep in mind that the output file must not already exist and that the
> user MySQL is running as has write permissions to the directory MySQL
> is attempting to write the file to.

**Syntax**

```
   SELECT Your_Column_Name
    FROM Your_Table_Name
    INTO OUTFILE 'Filename.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Or you could try to grab the output via the client:

> You could try executing the query from the your local client and
> redirect the output to a local file destination:

```
mysql -user -pass -e "select cols from table where cols not null" > /tmp/output
```

Hint: If you don't specify an absolute path but use something like `INTO OUTFILE  'output.csv'` or `INTO OUTFILE './output.csv'`, it will store the output file to the directory specified by `show variables like 'datadir';`.

Comment: The MySQL username is not a system username, and thus cannot by definition have right access to anything, not even to /tmp. What is even the point of using the mysql userid instead of the effective userid to deduce writing permissions? Is there a way to bypass this (and I don't mean by creating a new system user).

Comment: It's important to note that this create the file in the server. As the docs of select into explains, you'll have to use the mysql command as mysql -e "select ...". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: Just a note to say that if you get this error: `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`, you can stillsave the file in `/var/lib/mysql-files/` (Debian) and move it to your desired location after.

Comment: This does not work in most cases where you are a client and the file is being created on the server machine that the client does not have access any way.  I voted down this answer.

Comment: If the server is running under SELinux in enforcing mode, the file might appear to write but when you look, the file's not there.  To get around this you can specify a file path where the server is allowed to write, e.g. '/var/lib/mysql/output.txt'.  I hope it won't let you overwrite anything important, but be careful with the file names.

Comment: On shared hosting, this might work but accessing that file is damn near impossible

Comment: `mysql -e statement` is short-hand for `mysql --execute=statement`

Comment: I got this: The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Finally, I used https://tableconvert.com/mysql-to-excel to convert mysql query output to excel format

Answer (score 14):

You can write following codes to achieve this task:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... 
INTO OUTFILE 'textfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

It export the result to CSV and then export it to excel sheet.

Comment: got error code: 1045 Access denied

Comment: @user2568374 your mysql user do not have permission to write inside folder you specified. you can run this directly from command line as: mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -e "select ... from database.table where ..." > desired/file.txt

Comment: Can't create/write to file, Permission denied !!! (I'm root). Updates: I knew how to fix the error, we need to give the folder's permission 1777, example : chmod 1777 /var/lib/mysql-files/