# Error while sending output of a mysql query to a csv file

Tags: mysql

could somebody help me with the following query, I am pretty new

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns Where TABLE_SCHEMA='test';
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'; 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Thank you.

Comment: What error you getting. Post that

Comment: there is just red outlines and those are indicating that wrong syntax

Comment: Please remove semi colon in first two lines

Comment: Mark answer/Upvote for your questions if it's helped. May it will be useful for future reference

Comment: @VigneshKumar Thank you my friend. you have helped me with two issues. the below answer helped me but I am unable to locate the csv file which contains the output.

Comment: @VigneshKumar it is saying still time is there to wait. I can do after that.\

Comment: Not only this man. I think your previous question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file/21253740?noredirect=1#comment32019881_21253740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns Where TABLE_SCHEMA='test'
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Why have you mentioned `;` this in all the rows??

MySQL may be writing the file into its own data directory, like 
`/var/lib/mysql/<databasename>` for example. To specify the path, use a full path.

However, it must be a directory that is writable by the user account the MySQL server daemon is running under.
 For that reason, I'll often use /tmp:

Specify the path you want to write to as in:

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mydata.csv'
```

Comment: BTW may I know where the file have been saved ?

Comment: Check in My documents

Comment: No , its not placed in My Documents.

Comment: @rajagenupula: Or, give absolute path for outfile.

Comment: @rajagenupula i have updated my answer check with that

Comment: shall we speak for windows please

Comment: @It is similar for Windows too except file separator.