# Format SQL Table data as Text Table

Tags: mysql, oracle, formatting, format

I have a result from Oracle database as below:

```
1   Chi Phí Lương   FA_Phan_Bo_Chi_Phi_Luong    8   JOHN    8   2015    (BLOB)  FA_Phan_Bo_Chi_Phi_Luong_Final.csv  09-NOV-15   Đã Hoàn Thành
2   Tổng Hợp TimeSheet Nhân Viên    FA_Tong_Hop_Timesheet   8   JOHN    8   2015    (BLOB)  FA_Tong_Hop_Timesheet_COM_Final.csv 09-NOV-15   Đã Hoàn Thành
3   Tổng Hợp Doanh Thu  FA_Tong_Hop_Doanh_Thu   8   JOHN    8   2015    (BLOB)  FA_Tong_Hop_Doanh_Thu_Final.csv 09-NOV-15   Đã Hoàn Thành
4   Chi Phí Hoạt Động Công Ty   FA_CP_Hoat_Dong 8   JOHN    8   2015    (BLOB)  FA_CP_Hoat_Dong_Final.csv   09-NOV-15   Đã Hoàn Thành
5   Khấu Hao Máy Móc Thiết Bị   FA_CP_Khau_Hao_Phan_Bo_MMTB 8   JOHN    8   2015    (BLOB)  FA_CP_Khau_Hao_Phan_Bo_MMTB_Final.csv   09-NOV-15   Đã Hoàn Thành
```

How can I format text as a table with the same width of column?

Comment: if the question is about SQLPlus you can set `COLUMN col_name FORMAT A24` where 24 is width of your column... if not - your can use rpad() function to align your text

Comment: Check the manual of your SQL client, maybe that can do it

Comment: How do you want it formatted (Padding Columns with spaces; HTML/DOC/ODF/RTF/LaTeX document; something else)? What are the BLOB columns and how do you expect them formatted? Can you provide an idea of your expected/ideal output.

Comment: I have given some formatting examples. See my answer @Quann . You can still accept my answer :P

Answer (score 2):

Your text sql result:

```
+---+------------------------------+-----------------------------+---+------+---+------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 1 | Chi Phí Lương                | FA_Phan_Bo_Chi_Phi_Luong    | 8 | JOHN | 8 | 2015 | (BLOB) | FA_Phan_Bo_Chi_Phi_Luong_Final.csv    | 09-NOV-15 | Đã Hoàn Thành |
+---+------------------------------+-----------------------------+---+------+---+------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 2 | Tổng Hợp TimeSheet Nhân Viên | FA_Tong_Hop_Timesheet       | 8 | JOHN | 8 | 2015 | (BLOB) | FA_Tong_Hop_Timesheet_COM_Final.csv   | 09-NOV-15 | Đã Hoàn Thành |
+---+------------------------------+-----------------------------+---+------+---+------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 3 | Tổng Hợp Doanh Thu           | FA_Tong_Hop_Doanh_Thu       | 8 | JOHN | 8 | 2015 | (BLOB) | FA_Tong_Hop_Doanh_Thu_Final.csv       | 09-NOV-15 | Đã Hoàn Thành |
+---+------------------------------+-----------------------------+---+------+---+------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 4 | Chi Phí Hoạt Động Công Ty    | FA_CP_Hoat_Dong             | 8 | JOHN | 8 | 2015 | (BLOB) | FA_CP_Hoat_Dong_Final.csv             | 09-NOV-15 | Đã Hoàn Thành |
+---+------------------------------+-----------------------------+---+------+---+------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 5 | Khấu Hao Máy Móc Thiết Bị    | FA_CP_Khau_Hao_Phan_Bo_MMTB | 8 | JOHN | 8 | 2015 | (BLOB) | FA_CP_Khau_Hao_Phan_Bo_MMTB_Final.csv | 09-NOV-15 | Đã Hoàn Thành |
+---+------------------------------+-----------------------------+---+------+---+------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

You can generate text tables at [tablesgenerator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) like following formats.

**You can give input as:**

1. SQL result in File -> Paste Table Data
2. File -> Import CSV File
3. Or you can generate table manually

Here you can align column values to left, right, centre.

Without Using Unicode symbols for table borders

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+
| id | name        | gender | state | age |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+
| 1  | John Kenedy | male   | NY    | 32  |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+
| 2  | Meresa Oslo | female | HI    | 26  |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+
| 3  | Mike Lanes  | male   | FL    | 25  |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+
```

Useing Unicode symbols for table borders

```
╔════╦═════════════╦════════╦═══════╦═════╗
║ id ║ name        ║ gender ║ state ║ age ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════╣
║ 1  ║ John Kenedy ║ male   ║ NY    ║ 32  ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════╣
║ 2  ║ Meresa Oslo ║ female ║ HI    ║ 26  ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════╬═══════╬═════╣
║ 3  ║ Mike Lanes  ║ male   ║ FL    ║ 25  ║
╚════╩═════════════╩════════╩═══════╩═════╝
```

Markdown table

```
| id | name        | gender | state | age |
|----|-------------|--------|-------|-----|
| 1  | John Kenedy | male   | NY    | 32  |
| 2  | Meresa Oslo | female | HI    | 26  |
| 3  | Mike Lanes  | male   | FL    | 25  |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL*Plus or TOAD or SQL*Navigator or SQL*Developer or whatever, use the features of what you are using to format output nicely.

If you're looking for a pure-database solution (no client), I use DBMS_SQL for this.  Here's the basic code (below).  This version just writes the result set to DBMS_OUTPUT.  You could change that to whatever you want.  Also, you'd need to extend it to handle data types beyond just `NUMBER`, `DATE`, and `VARCHAR2`.

```
DECLARE
  l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;

-- This is the procedure to format cursor output nicely
  PROCEDURE dump_cursor( p_rc IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    -- Dump the results of p_rc to log

    l_cursor                INTEGER;
    l_column_count          INTEGER;
    l_column_descriptions   sys.DBMS_SQL.desc_tab;
    l_status                INTEGER;
    l_column_value          VARCHAR2 (4000);
    l_column_width          NUMBER;
    l_rec_count             NUMBER := 0;
    l_line VARCHAR2(4000);


    FUNCTION get_length (l_column_def IN sys.DBMS_SQL.desc_rec)
      RETURN NUMBER IS
      l_width   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      l_width   := l_column_def.col_max_len;
      l_width   :=
        CASE l_column_def.col_type
          WHEN 12 THEN /* DATE */
                      20
          WHEN 2 THEN /* NUMBER */
                     10
          ELSE l_width
        END;
      -- Don't display more than 256 characters of any one column
      l_width   := LEAST(256,GREATEST (l_width, l_column_def.col_name_len));

      RETURN l_width;
    END get_length;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format=''DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS''';

    l_cursor := sys.DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(p_rc);

    -- Describe columns
    sys.DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (c => l_cursor, col_cnt => l_column_count, desc_t => l_column_descriptions);

    l_line := '';
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_column_count LOOP
      l_column_width   := get_length (l_column_descriptions (i));

      l_line := l_line || RPAD (l_column_descriptions (i).col_name, l_column_width);
      l_line := l_line || ' ';
      DBMS_SQL.define_column (l_cursor, i, l_column_value, 4000);
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_line);

    l_line := '';
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_column_count LOOP
      l_column_width   := get_length (l_column_descriptions (i));

      l_line := l_line || RPAD ('-', l_column_width, '-');
      l_line := l_line || ' ';
      DBMS_SQL.define_column (l_cursor, i, l_column_value, 4000);
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_line);

--   l_status   := sys.DBMS_SQL.execute (l_cursor);

    WHILE (sys.DBMS_SQL.fetch_rows (l_cursor) > 0) LOOP
      l_rec_count   := l_rec_count + 1;

    l_line := '';
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_column_count LOOP
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (l_cursor, i, l_column_value);
        l_column_value := translate(l_column_value,chr(10), chr(200));
        l_column_width   := get_length (l_column_descriptions (i));

        IF l_column_value IS NULL THEN
          l_line := l_line || RPAD (' ', l_column_width);
        ELSE
          l_line := l_line || RPAD (l_column_value, l_column_width);
        END IF;

        l_line := l_line || ' ';
      END LOOP;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_line);
    END LOOP;

    IF l_rec_count = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No data found.');
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_rec_count || ' rows returned.');
    END IF;

    sys.DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (l_cursor);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format=''DD-MON-YYYY''';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format=''DD-MON-YYYY''';

      RAISE;
  END dump_cursor;

-- This shows how to use it...
BEGIN

  OPEN l_rc FOR SELECT object_id, object_name, object_type, last_ddl_time FROM dba_objects WHERE rownum <= 100;
  dump_cursor(l_rc);
END;
```