# How to export result of run query in SQL when it gives 1045 error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, export

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,
       wp_posts.post_author,
       wp_users.ID,
       wp_users.display_name
FROM   wp_posts,
       wp_users
WHERE  wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID
       AND wp_users.ID != 1
```

This gives me result

[image: result]

Now I want to export this result I obtained from query in phpmyadmin.

For that I did this, as per answer given to me here below.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,
       wp_posts.post_author,
       wp_users.ID,
       wp_users.display_name
FROM   wp_posts,
       wp_users
WHERE  wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID
       AND wp_users.ID != 1 
INTO OUTFILE 'D:\backup\export.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

It gives me error

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save mysql query output to excel or .txt file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,
       wp_posts.post_author,
       wp_users.ID,
       wp_users.display_name
FROM   wp_posts,
       wp_users
WHERE  wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID
       AND wp_users.ID != 1 
INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\.....' --path to store the export data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

More info can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html)

Comment: It should be your hard drive path

Comment: #1045 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You need to have write access to the directory where you are creating the file.

Comment: Server. The above query will create a new file in the mentioned path so you need to have write permission in that directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101685/discussion-between-siren-brown-and-vr46).