# How can I execute an SQL file, and save the results to a txt file in one command?

Tags: mysql

I am using an Ubuntu terminal. I've found answers about running .sql files, and how to save query results to an external file. How can I do them both at the same time?

I've tried this command: `source /path/to/file.sql into outfile /path/to/outfile.txt`.

I've tried to add `into outfile /path/to/outfile.txt` directly into `file.sql` and running `source /path/to/outfile.sql`.

I've tried `mysql -u <username> -p <database> file.sql > results.txt.` If I switch `file.sql` with something like this `-e "select * from myTable"`, then it works fine.

How can I do this?

EDIT: Here is `file.sql`

```
select myID from Players where score > 80;
```

It's a simple query, but if I can figure this thing out, I can try to do bigger queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file

Answer (score 16):

Your answer is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html

> You can execute SQL statements in a script file (batch file) like this:
>
> shell> mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab

Try this: `mysql -u username -p database < file.sql > results.txt`

Answer (score 1):

@FLefèvre has a solution but I couldn't get it to work. It just outputted a MySQL help page where it shows the different commands.

Add this to the sql file: `.... into outfile '/path/to/outfile.txt'`. Single or double quotations on the path. And then in the MySQL shell, just do `source /path/to/file.sql`.

Comment: My answer works I tested it. The problem with your solution is that you need to modify the file content each time you want to change the results file. It's not a problem of course if you never reuse it... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql -u root -p -e"`cat /path/to/file.sql`" > result.txt
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.