# MySQL convert table to JSON file

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb, mariasql

I am working with a remote CentOS machine. I don't have graphical access, and I am just using a terminal. On the remote machine, I have a MySQL database with a table. I execute the command `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 10` to get the first 10 entries.

Now, I'd like to save this result in a JSON file on the machine. Eventually, I will do this for the whole table, not just 10 elements. I followed [this tutorial](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-from-sql-tables-to-json-documents-and-back-again/), but it doesn't actually create a JSON file on the disk. How do I do this?

Comment: Didn't you kinda miss the creation of a JSON String output if your quesry is just what you wrote

Comment: One way I found using SEARCH was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332994/write-results-of-sql-query-to-a-file-in-mysql

Comment: And another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368425/how-can-i-execute-an-sql-file-and-save-the-results-to-a-txt-file-in-one-command

Comment: @RiggsFolly - This is not an "exact duplicate".  The key difference is "JSON".  The OP needs to convert the data to JSON first; the dup does not do that.

Comment: The additional problem is that older versions of MySQL and MariaDB have no way to create JSON.  (At least not without lots of ugly CONCATs.)

Comment: So, the first question is "What version are you running?"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a suitably new version of MySQL (8.0), and you can craft a JSON expression with JSON_ARRAYAGG, JSON_OBJECT, etc, then you can write that to a file by using the

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE '...' ...
```

syntax.