# Export mysql query to amazon s3 bucket

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file), I am able to export the results of mysql query to a `csv` file on my Amazon EC2 instance using the following:

```
mysql -user -pass -e "SELECT * FROM table" > /data.csv
```

However, as the file exported is large, I want to export an Amazon s3-bucket (`s3:\\mybucket`) which is accessible from my EC2 instance

I tried:

```
mysql -user -pass -e "SELECT * FROM table" > s3:\\mybucket\data.csv
```

But it doesn't export the file.

Comment: You will have to do it in 2 steps, first safe the file to your instance and then send it to S3.

Comment: @jarnohenneman but the output file is bigger than the instance disk space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the mysql command line program, then you have two choices:

- Increase the size of your instance's storage so that the file can be created. Then copy the file to S3
- Create a separate program or script that reads from Standard Input and writes to S3.

Another solution would be to create a simple program that processes your SELECT and directly writes to S3. There are lots of examples of this on the Internet in Python, Java, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you are using the Aurora, then you can do

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE S3 's3:\\mybucket\table-data';
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

Alternate approach,

```
mysqldump -h [db_hostname] -u [db_user] -p[db_passwd] [databasename] [tablename] | aws s3 cp - s3://[s3_bucketname]/[mysqldump_filename]
```

it'll directly store the file to s3 without occupying space