# Write the result of an SQL query to a file

Tags: sql, mysql

how can I write the result of a SQL query to a txt file?
E.g.

```
select * from user where age => 18;
```

I tried

```
select * from users where age =>18 into outfile /home/me/result_sql_query.txt
```

But it didn't work.

My goal is to have the result in the
`result_sql_query.txt`
file.

Comment: SQL itself has no such functionality. But the query tool probably has.

Comment: Duplicate [How to save MySQL query output to excel or .txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file)

Comment: `select ... into outfile` puts the file **on the server**, not your local machine. Even if the server is running locally, it probably does not have permission to write to /hone/me. Your SQL client should have a way to write results to a file.

Comment: _Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._

Answer (score 0):

Use `>=` for comparision and quotation marks around the filename:

```
select * from users where age >= 18 into outfile '/home/me/result_sql_query.txt'
```

Note that MySQL needs to have permsissions to create the file.

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).