# Finding the tables where a view is derived from in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a view in MySQL called `myview` that has 3 fields: `col1`, `col1`, `col3`.

I would like to figure out where these columns came from, e.g., which table does `col1` live in? And `col2`? etc.

I can find out where `col1` comes from by using

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'col1'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='lava_mac';
```

From this I would get 2 matches,

```
myview  
tableWithCol1
```

This is great, but I really want to extend this query in such a way that I get a result like:

```
col1         col2          col3  
tableWithCo1 tableWithCol2 tableWithCol3
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752116/mysql-select-all-tables-with-multiple-specific-columns) is similar, but not the same.  Does anyone have any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Mysql version
[How to find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

SQL Server version: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 (Group_Concat)**

If you know the name of the view you could do something such as:

```
select
GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) as columns,
GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) as tables 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = "myView";
```

Data:

```
columns         tables
col1,col2,col3  myview,myview,myview
```

**Approach 2 (Simple)**

```
  select
    COLUMN_NAME,
    TABLE_NAME 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = "myView";
```

**Approach 3 (CASE with ALIAS)**

Unfortunately mysql does not have transpose, so you must hardcode the column names like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'col1' THEN TABLE_NAME END) as `col1`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'col2' THEN TABLE_NAME END) as `col2`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'col3' THEN TABLE_NAME END) as `col3`
  FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME like "myView%";
```

SQLFIddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceb96e/10

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking a

```
                     SHOW CREATE VIEW myview
```

statement would return what you're looking for.

(Is there a need to re-invent the wheel, or maybe I'm not understanding the question.)

Comment: Nice one... not exactly the format the op asked for but ok. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceb96e/11