# SQL list all tables with certain column names

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

I'd like to make a SQL query to a MySQL 5.6 server to return me all the tables that contains AT LEAST the following column names:

```
field1 
field2
```

I've seen examples here but they only cover having exactly one column name or one between many possible.

For example, if I have these 4 tables:

```
TABLE1
field1 field2 field3

TABLE2
field2 field4

TABLE3
field1 field3

TABLE4
field1 field2
```

Since I'm querying the tables that have AT LEAST "field1" **AND** "field2", the result should be:

```
TABLE1
TABLE4
```

I tried doing a self join with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table but I can't get it right...

Thanks for your help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them

Comment: This is not correct, because it will show those with "field1" OR "field2" and I want both of them. I already tested before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T2 ON(T1.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME)
WHERE T1.COLUMN_NAME = 'field1'
AND T2.COLUMN_NAME = 'field2'
```

**Note**: code was written directly here, not tested.

Comment: Ah you are right! I did this but I forgot putting T1 in SELECT DISTINCT T1.TABLE_NAME :_D

Thank you!!!

Comment: Small typo on T2..COLUMN_NAME though

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'field1' OR COLUMN_NAME = 'field2'
```

This should return **EVERY** table name which has a column named 'field1' or 'field2'.

Comment: OP wants every table to have both columns, not either column.