# search record in multiple tables and print output differently in mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have four tables in my database. `TABLE1` having 5 columns, `TABLE2` having 7, `TABLE3` having 9 and `TABLE4` having 11 columns respectively.

all 4 tables have a column `PID`, from which i want to make a user query. i.e.

```
SELECT pid FROM ....
```

the problem i am facing, is, how to choose from all the 4 tables, if my query is not found in `TABLE1` then search in `TABLE2`, and so on.

since all tables have different structure, the result must pass differently for output, like, if query was found in `TABLE1` the output would have a table with 5 columns, or if from `TABLE4` the output would show 11 columns.

for now, i can make a query for only 1 table.

```
<h2>title</h2>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">SELECT NAME FROM LIST</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <form name="dropdown" action="http://search.php" method="post">
            <select class="form-control" data-style="btn-primary" name="p_ID">
<?php
//provide your hostname, username and dbname
$host="localhost"; 
$username="root";  
$password="";
$db_name="mydb"; 
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$sql = "select PID from TABLE1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=$row[PID]>$row[PID]</option>";
}
?>

    </select><br><br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary center-block btn-lg" type="submit" >Search</button>
                </form> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is from `Search.php` for the output table.

```
<?php   

//provide your hostname, username and dbname
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = 'mydb';
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if(!$mysqli) 
{
    echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
} 
else 
{
if(isset($_POST[PID]) )
{
//echo "Input by list<br>";

$query = "select * from TABLE1 where PID like '$_POST[PID]%' ";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    //$arr = array();
    if($result->num_rows <= 1) 
    {
    echo "<table class=\"table\" ><tr><th>Protein ID:</th>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        echo "<td>$row[PID]</td><tr><th>Protein Domain:</th><td>$row[p_name]</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Interacting Proteins:</th><td>";
        $seqsplit1 = wordwrap($row[p_symbol_orf], 60, "-\n", true);
        echo "$seqsplit1</td>";

        echo "</tr><tr><th>Protein Sequence:</th><td><div>";
        $seqsplit = wordwrap($row[p_sequence], 60, "\n", true);
        echo ">$row[p_ts]<br>$seqsplit";
        echo "</div></td></tr><tr><th>Protein Length:</th><td>$row[p_length]</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>";

        }
        ?>          

<?php       

    echo "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No query found, please search next!";
    }
}
```

these are the structure of following tables

```
TABLE1
PID PNAME PSYMBOL PSEQ PLEN

TABLE2
PID PNAME1 PSYMBOL1 PNAME2 PSYMBOL2  PSEQ PLEN

TABLE3
PID PNAME1 PSYMBOL1 PNAME2 PSYMBOL2 PNAME3 PSYMBOL3 PSEQ PLEN

TABLE4
PID PNAME1 PSYMBOL1 PNAME2 PSYMBOL2 PNAME3 PSYMBOL3 PNAME4 PSYMBOL4 PSEQ PLEN
```

Comment: then you have a bad sql structure. not possible to do an if exist user 123 on multiple tables select. user must exist on all tables or simply dont exist. In any case you must define an user role at code level. so a a admin or client or employee can only select from specific tables

Comment: @RedAcid please explain

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select * from TABLE1 where PID like '$_POST[PID]%'  ";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
if($result->num_rows == 0){
    $query = "select * from TABLE2 where PID like '$_POST[PID]%'  ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}else if($result->num_rows == 0){
    $query = "select * from TABLE3 where PID like '$_POST[PID]%'  ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}else if($result->num_rows == 0){
    $query = "select * from TABLE4 where PID like '$_POST[PID]%'  ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}else if($result->num_rows == 0){
    $query = "select * from TABLE5 where PID like '$_POST[PID]%'  ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}
```

to handle table column count conflict, you should use foreach statement

```
if($result->num_rows <= 1)    
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
       foreach ($row as $r1=>$r){
           echo $r1.": ".$r."<br/>"; ...
       }
```

Comment: isn't there any change to be made in the index.php page. since it is selecting elements from only TABLE1