# How to get all the tables' name having specific column name using any query?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have 4 tables, named:-

1. tbl_user
2. tbl_doctor
3. tbl_chat_request
4. tbl_payment

Now three tables have a field called `users_id`

Is there are query which can tell me all the tables which has a field with column name `users_id`?

I don't even have any idea if it is possible or not.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them?rq=1

Comment: I checked , the bellow answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get table name from schema like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='users_id'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name';
```

Comment: Its returning blank result

Comment: pass your db_name in table_schema ..it will surely work

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='Your Column Name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='Your Database Name'
```