# How do I find a table in MySQL with 2 specific columns in it

Tags: mysql

Similar to [How to find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them) I would like to find the table with 2 specific columns, not either or.

I've tried combining with AND but no dice.

For instance, I want to search the database for the specific tables that contain both CategoryID and LotNumber columns.

Comment: Just use that answer's query grouping by table name and having count(*) = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the [`information_schema.columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) table, grouping the matching columns by table and returning only those with number equal to 2:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE (column_name = 'colname1' OR column_name = 'colname2')
[AND table_schema = 'dbname']
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
SELECT * from TableName where obj1 = "obj1" and obj2= "obj2"
```

this is an example.

Let me know how it worked :)

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but perhaps I didn't ask my question well. I'm searching to find the table that has 2 specific columns in that same table.

Comment: Ohh I see  I did not get it for the first time :)