# How do I Select from all Tables a certain column to a string array in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need to get from each individual table but from the same column name the value to a `string array`. Although I don't what I table names I've got. I only know they all have a column name 'email'.

```
        string connectionString = "SERVER=********;PORT=****;DATABASE=********;UID=********;PASSWORD=******;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();


        try
        {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = "SHOW FULL TABLES FROM ExampleDataBase";
        }   


        catch 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("error"); 
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            string usermail = reader.GetString("email");

            string[] mail = new String[] { usermail};
            foreach (string s in mail)
            {
                listboxMails.Items.Add("email: " + s)
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the table names is not a good start when you work with DB...

First get a [list of all table name who have the `email` field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'email'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='ExampleDataBase';
```

Second generate a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) request with all your table name

like

```
(SELECT email FROM %myTable1%)
UNION
(SELECT email FROM %myTable2%)
-- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a name, it might be easiest to use Linq's mapping. Make sure to add the reference System.Linq.Data... Here's the code:

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

    namespace ...
    {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {                    
                    DataContext dataContext = new DataContext(connectionString);
                    Table<Email> Emails = dataContext.GetTable<Email>();
                    IQueryable<string> query = from e in Emails
                                               select $"email: {e.email}";


                }
            }

            [Table]
            public class Email
            {
                [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
                public string email;
            }
     }
```

This should be the easiest way to enumerate. I hope this helps.

Comment: you probably do not need the (IsPrimaryKey = true) as I doubt a DB would set a Primary Key column to a user's email address as this may be duplicated for multiple accounts.