# How to get columns' name from a table in sqlite3 database using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I already have read some answers on this. But all of them are giving me the same error.

**Here are the solutions I read:**

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server)

   ```
   import sqlite3 as sql

   #connect to database
   connection = sql.connect("database.db")

   #make a cursor which will move in the database
   cursor = connection.cursor()

   #execute the different command
   def execute(cursor, command):
       return cursor.execute(command)

   #print the result
   def print_result(result):
       for var in result:
           print(var)
   # select columns' name from table

   command = """select distinct emplyee from emplyee.information_schema.columns"""

   result = execute(cursor, command)
   print_result(result)
   ```

---

The table name is **emplyee**.

**Error is**:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "database.py", line 47, in

```
result = execute(cursor, command)
```

File "database.py", line 11, in execute

```
return cursor.execute(command)
```

sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

Comment: What database are you using?  You tagged MySQL and SQL Server, but the code indicates SQLite.

Comment: I am using SQLITE3 but i didn't know that they are different. I thought that basic commands must be same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support the information_schema, so you need to do something like this:

```
def table_columns(db, table_name)
    curs = db.cursor()
    sql = "select * from %s where 1=0;" % table_name
    curs.execute(sql)
    return [d[0] for d in curs.description]
```

Comment: It worked. But can u pls tell me what does 1=0 does here.

Comment: @AdarshMaurya it prevents the query from returning any data.

Comment: The expression `1=0` is not true for any row. Anyway, SQLite computes result rows on demand, so it's not needed.

Comment: The criteria of 1=0 does not select any rows because you aren't trying to get data; all you want is the table description that is in the cursor object.  There's no point in wasting time selecting data that you don't need.

Comment: imho this answer is slightly more superior because it is very specific to the query. if in your query you only have considered some of the columns, this will give your exactly those.

Answer (score 1):

Does the same thing but with more modern syntax. (You don't need to use cursors with execute() in sqlite3.)

```
import sqlite3

def get_col_names(file_name: str, table_name: str) -> List[str]:
    conn = sqlist3.connect(file_name)
    col_data = conn.execute(f'PRAGMA table_info({table_name});').fetchall()
    return [entry[1] for entry in col_data]
```