# Search in all tables for a field with given value or name

Tags: mysql

Is there a pure sql solution to search in all tables for a specific field with a given value or name. In pseudocode the query im looking for would be

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE field = "value"
```

or

```
SELECT tablename, field FROM *
```

I already know how I could use the mysql [information schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them) to search for all tables with the column, but I'm unsure if (and how) I could combine this inside a query (or stored procedure).

Comment: what is REAL problem You want to resolve?

Comment: i believe one one the best architecural patters is relational data (busines or transactional or simmilar meaning) and connected text searcher to some level 'offline' (lucene or simmilar, or extra functionality fro DB provider)

Comment: @JacekCz I  got a database dump with lots of tables, where some fields have invalid/missing foreign keys and now I have to fix this/dig into it. So the query don't need to be robust and only runs a few times

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script wich will generate all queries:

```
SELECT concat('SELECT * FROM ',TABLE_NAME,' WHERE ',COLUMN_NAME,' =\'value\'')
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'columnname'
;
```

Then, you can execute each rows of the result to get the needed data.

Comment: usefullnes of result is strongly limited