# combine select from information_schema and alter table from another data base

Tags: mysql, alter

I want to alter a table by modifying many columns from varchar(200) to tinytext
for one column i can use this request

```
ALTER TABLE contacts MODIFY "column_name" TINYTEXT
```

i can get a list of columns using this request

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= "base561"
AND COLUMN_TYPE="varchar(200)"
AND TABLE_NAME="contacts"
```

How i can combine both requests that i cant modify all my columns to TINYTEXT.

Thank you.

Comment: the is an answer for your issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512859/loop-through-all-tables-and-rename-a-column

Comment: no it doesn't unsewr my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through all tables and rename a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512859/loop-through-all-tables-and-rename-a-column)