# Deleting a row if a column exists in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete rows if `new_id` column value is equal to 2 from multiple mysql tables, but I don't know if all those tables have column `new_id`.

I try the following statement, but it gives a syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE new_id =2 IF EXISTS new_id int(11)
```

How to do this?

Comment: You can get all tables with that column name using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them) and then  create dynamic query to delete the data from the resultset of that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get column name by using below query

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name` LIKE 'new_id';
```

Then from frontend you can take the decision to execute delete query

Answer (score 1):

You can check in `information schema`:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
            FROM information_schema.columns 
            WHERE table_name = 'table_name' 
            AND column_name = 'new_id' 
            AND table_schema = DATABASE () ) THEN
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE new_id = 2;
END IF;
```